# Is it possible to combine 7 sources without a UNION?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssis, normalization

I have a source table that looks essentially like this:

- EmployeeCode
- WeekStartDate
- HoursWorkedDay1
- HoursWorkedDay2
- HoursWorkedDay3
- HoursWorkedDay4
- HoursWorkedDay5
- HoursWorkedDay6
- HoursWorkedDay7

The actual table has something like 500 numbered columns (didn't really count them - there are various and numerous fields numbered 1-7, and then another handful numbered 1-25, times 7) per weekday (no, that's not my design), and there are currently something like 38,600 rows (growing every week).

I have an SSIS package that's trying to normalize this data... that currently looks like this:

[image: union all]

Each "source" is selecting one set of numbered columns from the same source table, and the UNION ALL component combines the 7 sources into one, resulting in some 258,900 rows.

The rest of the workflow adds some calculated columns, looks up surrogate keys (e.g. `EmployeeCode` is used to lookup an `EmployeeId`, and then the date is computed and used for looking up a `TimeId`), and then the "modified" rows get updated and the "new" ones get inserted into a normalized table; unchanged rows end up nowhere.

Is there any better way (e.g. a bit less heavy on memory pressure) to normalize the source data?

Comment: @MaxVernon that sounds about right, but I've never used that transformation, and I'm confused as to what my Pivot Key Value might be here, given I have so many columns to deal with - the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141723.aspx) aren't very clear about how to do this and according to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2014/05/21/unvipot-transformation-with-a-combination-of-single-and-multiple-destination-columns/) I'd need... about 20 unpivot operations (given 20 "groups" of fields)? Is that less expensive than my union?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without the full table definition, it is difficult to provide a perfect answer.  However, in an attempt to show the differences in a limited repro, with a very small amount of data, I've created the following testbed:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#src') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #src;
CREATE TABLE #src
(
    EmployeeCode INT NOT NULL
    , WeekStartDate DATE NOT NULL
    , HoursDay1 INT NOT NULL
    , HoursDay2 INT NOT NULL
    , HoursDay3 INT NOT NULL
    , HoursDay4 INT NOT NULL
    , HoursDay5 INT NOT NULL
    , HoursDay6 INT NOT NULL
    , HoursDay7 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget1Day1 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget1Day2 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget1Day3 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget1Day4 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget1Day5 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget1Day6 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget1Day7 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget2Day1 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget2Day2 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget2Day3 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget2Day4 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget2Day5 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget2Day6 INT NOT NULL
    , Widget2Day7 INT NOT NULL
    , PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (WeekStartDate, EmployeeCode)
);
GO
INSERT INTO #src (EmployeeCode, WeekStartDate
    , HoursDay1, HoursDay2, HoursDay3, HoursDay4, HoursDay5, HoursDay6, HoursDay7
    , Widget1Day1, Widget1Day2, Widget1Day3, Widget1Day4, Widget1Day5, Widget1Day6, Widget1Day7
    , Widget2Day1, Widget2Day2, Widget2Day3, Widget2Day4, Widget2Day5, Widget2Day6, Widget2Day7
    )
VALUES (1, '2016-09-18'
    , 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0
    , ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
    , ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
    );
```

Below we are comparing the two queries; the first uses the `CROSS APPLY` method, detailed by me at [SQLServerScience.com](http://www.sqlserverscience.com/t-sql/cross-apply-as-an-alternative-to-unpivot/?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=dba.se.post&utm_campaign=150498), and the second uses the `UNION ALL` method.

```
SELECT s.WeekStartDate
    , s.EmployeeCode
    , ItemsByDay.DayOfWeekName
    , ItemsByDay.HoursWorked
    , ItemsByDay.Widget1
    , ItemsByDay.Widget2
FROM #src s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Sunday', HoursDay1, Widget1Day1, Widget2Day1)
    , ('Monday', HoursDay2, Widget1Day2, Widget2Day2)
    , ('Tuesday', HoursDay3, Widget1Day3, Widget2Day3)
    , ('Wednesday', HoursDay4, Widget1Day4, Widget2Day4)
    , ('Thursday', HoursDay5, Widget1Day5, Widget2Day5)
    , ('Friday', HoursDay6, Widget1Day6, Widget2Day6)
    , ('Saturday', HoursDay7, Widget1Day7, Widget2Day7)
    ) ItemsByDay(DayOfWeekName, HoursWorked, Widget1, Widget2);


SELECT s.EmployeeCode
    , s.WeekStartDate
    , 'Sunday'
    , s.HoursDay1
    , s.Widget1Day1
    , s.Widget2Day1
FROM #src s
UNION ALL
SELECT s.EmployeeCode
    , s.WeekStartDate
    , 'Monday'
    , s.HoursDay2
    , s.Widget1Day2
    , s.Widget2Day2
FROM #src s
UNION ALL
SELECT s.EmployeeCode
    , s.WeekStartDate
    , 'Tuesday'
    , s.HoursDay3
    , s.Widget1Day3
    , s.Widget2Day3
FROM #src s
UNION ALL
SELECT s.EmployeeCode
    , s.WeekStartDate
    , 'Wednesday'
    , s.HoursDay4
    , s.Widget1Day4
    , s.Widget2Day4
FROM #src s
UNION ALL
SELECT s.EmployeeCode
    , s.WeekStartDate
    , 'Thursday'
    , s.HoursDay5
    , s.Widget1Day5
    , s.Widget2Day5
FROM #src s
UNION ALL
SELECT s.EmployeeCode
    , s.WeekStartDate
    , 'Friday'
    , s.HoursDay6
    , s.Widget1Day6
    , s.Widget2Day6
FROM #src s
UNION ALL
SELECT s.EmployeeCode
    , s.WeekStartDate
    , 'Saturday'
    , s.HoursDay7
    , s.Widget1Day7
    , s.Widget2Day7
FROM #src s;
```

First thing to note, the `CROSS APPLY` is easier to look at.  This already makes me happy.

Lets check the execution plans for the two variants:

[image]

The `UNION ALL` variant scans the source table 7 times, whereas the `CROSS APPLY` uses a single table scan.  By using the cross apply, we're #Winning.

Let's add more data:

```
/* create a table with 2 years worth of week start dates */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Weeks') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Weeks
    (
        WeekStart DATE NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    );

    INSERT INTO #Weeks (WeekStart)
    SELECT TOP(104) DATEADD(DAY, (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o1.name) - 1) * 7, '2016-01-03')
    FROM sys.objects o1
        CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2;
END

/* remove the single row from the source table we inserted above */
TRUNCATE TABLE #src;

/* insert a load of rows into the #src table */
INSERT INTO #src (EmployeeCode, WeekStartDate, HoursDay1, HoursDay2, HoursDay3, HoursDay4, HoursDay5, HoursDay6, HoursDay7)
SELECT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
    , w.WeekStart
    , 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 0
FROM #Weeks w
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects o1;
```

On my system the above code generated around 85,000 rows.  The plans for the two queries are now:

[image]

[SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](https://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view) shows the following summary information, which is invaluable:

[image]

This says the CPU is used more intensively by the `CROSS APPLY`, however there is 7 times more I/O used by the `UNION ALL` variant.

Comment: Awesome, never seen `CROSS APPLY` used like this! FWIW it's 118x7 columns I'm combining here (I know, it's completely indecent!); the single table-scan issued 270,179 rows in 48 seconds - I'm shoving that query into a view and using that as my SSIS source now!

Comment: Just did a comparison with `UNION ALL` (took a while to alias all 118x7 columns!)... 7 table-scans issues 270,179 rows in ...20 seconds. And now I'm torn :(

Comment: LOL, maybe try the cross apply again.  Perhaps the data was not cached the first time?

Comment: hmm that's right - 24-26 seconds now, and the rows start streaming in immediately. Based on your I/O vs CPU profiling I'm going to go with the `CROSS APPLY`, these 5-6 seconds are sparing a toll on the server aren't they?

Comment: You should be seeing about 7x less I/O with the `CROSS APPLY`.  That's typically a good thing.